# Cannot ssh from Jenkins build step

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to ssh into an Ubuntu 16.04 server from a Jenkins build step but get "Permission denied, please try again".

However, i can ssh using the terminal from the Jenkins server to the Ubuntu 16.04 server without an issue.

On the Jenkins server my permissions look correct:

```
drwx------  2 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 May 11 09:07 .ssh/

-rw-------  1 ubuntu ubuntu 1679 May 11  2018 id_rsa

-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  392 May 11  2018 id_rsa.pub
```

On the Ubuntu 16.04 server my permissions look correct:

```
drwx------  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 May 11 11:16 .ssh

-rw-------  1 ubuntu ubuntu  392 May 11 11:16 authorized_keys
```

Im rather confused as to why the Jenkins build step cannot ssh correctly, am i missing some configuration for the Jenkins build step?

See a [screen shot of the Jenkins build step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOI5I.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try changing the ssh command to `ssh -v ...`, so it is in `verbose` mode & output more details, then check jenkins output? Or did you try with `ssh  -i  /path/to/id_rsa  ubuntu@....` to specify the path to private key?

Comment: This probably means that Jenkins cannot access the ssh certificate files.   Are you sure that the user Jenkins is running under can access the `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` files? I usually use the `Credentials` plugin and store this there to avoid this problem as our setup is a bit more complicated and is running inside docker anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> Im rather confused as to why the Jenkins build step cannot ssh correctly

- because of this:

  ```
  -rw-------  1 ubuntu ubuntu 1679 May 11  2018 id_rsa
  ```

  this means that your **ubuntu** user can ssh from jenkins server - not your **jenkins** user. In order for your jenkins user to be able to ssh you either need to configure username/password for it (shell is disabled by default for jenkins user, you can enable it manually) and place credentials in it's .ssh folder, or use Credentials plugin as suggested.